# why lista.sort() + listb.sort() doesn't work in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I tried this code in python and it works perfectly:

```
listX.sort()
list1.sort()

result = listX + list1
```

but the following code doesn't work:

```
result = listX.sort() + list1.sort()
```

it gives me this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Besides being a dup, this is also answered in the Python FAQ (which even explains _why_ Python was designed this way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `list.sort()` returns `None`, so you are effectively doing:

```
None + None
```

which doesn't even make sense.

If you want to concatenate the sorted elements of two lists, you can either do:

```
listA.sort()
listB.sort()
listC = listA + listB
```

or, (recommended):

```
listC = sorted(listA) + sorted(listB)
```

as `sorted()` *does* return a value.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `list.sort` method operates on the list in place, returning `None`.  In contrast, `sorted` is a builtin function which does *return* the sorted output.

```
result = sorted(listX) + sorted(list1)
```

That would do what you want.

Comment: I noticed that I basically repeated your answer, so I wiki'd my answer. +1

Comment: That makes very little sense to me, but ... OK!  :D

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, now that I think about it... It doesn't. Oh well.